# Is there a function in R Survey library that tests equality of weighted proportions for a single variable?

Tags: r, survey, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

Let's say I have a survey question on political party affiliation - Democrat, Republican, Independent, Other.  I want to test whether the weighted proportions are equal.

I cannot use Base R functions because they don't take account of sampling weights in the calculation of variance.

I have tried svychisq() but that only works for testing for association between two variables.

Comment: how about `stats::prop.trend.test()`?

Comment: @DavidZ  Thanks for the comment, but that will not work for several reasons.  I have never used prop.trend.test() before, but it looks like it is testing for a trend, e.g., increasing or decreasing.  My data is not ordinal, so there doesn't have to be a trend for there to be differences between proportions.  Also, the test does not account for the sampling design.  I believe only R Survey accounts for the sampling design when performing tests.